# Python pandas with freqtrade

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm use python pandas with freqttade.
I have a dataframe like this

```
[
'high', 'low', 'up', 'trend'
123, 112, 0, 0
222, 121, 1, 0
333, 231, 1, 0
555, 444, 0, 0
231, 211, 0, 0
]
```

based on UP data i want to fill trend

```
# example
dataframe.loc[
    (dataframe["up"] == 1)
, "trend"] = dataframe["high"] / dataframe["low"]

# get prev trend if up == 0
dataframe.loc[
    (dataframe["up"] == 0)
, "trend"] = dataframe["trend"].shift(1)
```

what do i get as output

```
[
'high', 'low', 'up', 'trend'
123, 112, 0, 0
222, 121, 1, 1.83
333, 231, 1, 1.44
555, 444, 0, 1.44 - this is what i get
231, 211, 0, 1.44 - and this is no longer
]
```

I understand that the data in the column TREND at the time of receiving the previous one does not yet exist, but how can this be implemented?

if column UP == 0 then get previous data

EDIT condition:

```
dataframe["trend"].fillna(0.0)
# up
dataframe.loc[
    (dataframe["up"] == 1)
, "trend"] = dataframe["low"] - dataframe['high']

# down
dataframe.loc[
    (dataframe["up"] == -1)
, "trend"] = dataframe["high"] + dataframe['low']

# if up == 0, get prev data
dataframe.loc[
    (dataframe["up"] == 0)
, "trend"] = dataframe["trend"].shift(1)
```

if add loop, fixed it (but it's a very bad idea) but it works, how to solve without such a crutch?

```
maxRange = len(dataframe.trend)
for x in range(maxRange)
    dataframe.loc[
        (dataframe["up"] == 0)
    , "trend"] = dataframe["trend"].shift(1)
```

Comment: what is your desired output? trend column = 0 1.83 1.44 1.44 0?

Comment: 1.83 - 1.44 - 1.44 - 1.44

Comment: where's column "TrendLine" ?

Comment: sorry, trend = trendline

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'high': {0: 123, 1: 222, 2: 333, 3: 555, 4: 231},
        'low': {0: 112, 1: 121, 2: 231, 3: 444, 4: 211},
        'up': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    high    low up
0   123     112 0
1   222     121 1
2   333     231 1
3   555     444 0
4   231     211 0
```

**Code**

```
df['high'].div(df['low']).where(df['up'].eq(1)).ffill()
```

result:

```
0   NaN
1   1.83
2   1.44
3   1.44
4   1.44
dtype: float64
```

make result to trend column

```
df.assign(trend=df['high'].div(df['low']).where(df['up'].eq(1)).ffill())
```

output:

```
    high    low up  trend
0   123     112 0   NaN
1   222     121 1   1.83
2   333     231 1   1.44
3   555     444 0   1.44
4   231     211 0   1.44
```

Comment: thanks, maybe it works on one condition, but if 3 condition up == 1 and up == -1, rest 0 take previous? Edited (add code)